# how to expand clist_if_in parameter in expl3

Tags: expl3

How to expand parameter `l_element_b` in `clist_if_in` condition in expl3? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_some_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_some_clist {A,B}

\str_set:Nx \l_element_b {B}

\bool_set_false:N \l_a_bool 
\clist_if_in:NoTF \l_some_clist {\l_element_b} {\bool_set_true:N \l_a_bool} {} % <-- false

\bool_set_false:N \l_b_bool 
\clist_if_in:NoTF \l_some_clist {B} {\bool_set_true:N \l_b_bool} {} % <-- true

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_if:NTF \l_a_bool {a:true} {a:false} \\
\bool_if:NTF \l_b_bool {b:true} {b:false} \\
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what you want is `\tl_set:Nx \l_element_b_tl {B}`, instead of `\str_set:Nx`. Or even `\tl_set:Nn` if the `x`-type expansion carried by `\edef` is not needed.

According to the latex3 doc (`texdoc interface3`), chap. 16 "*The `l3str` package: Strings*"

> A TeX string (and thus an `expl3` string) is a series of characters which have category code 12 (“other”) with the exception of space characters which have category code 10 (“space”). Thus at a technical level, a TeX string is a token list with the appropriate category codes. In this documentation, these are simply referred to as strings.

Hence after `\str_set:Nx \l_element_b {B}` (I would suggest to name it `\l_element_b_str`), `\l_element_b` holds `B` with category code 12 ("other"). A `B` with category code 11 ("letter") is in `\l_some_clist`, but a `B` with category code 12 is not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it solved my problem, and I will change my variable name as you suggested.